# Magnento 2 add file upload field on customer registration page and display in backend

Tags: magento2, customer-account, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file(mostly likely image) from customer registration form.

Answer (score 2):

You need create first one eav attribute in db table. Also you can check link for create customer with image upload.

https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-customer-image-file-upload-in-registration-account-page/

Comment: yes i did by creating csutom attribute and on registration success event i saved that attribute value.